# Cannot use process.env variable to set an alias in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

In build\webpack.base.conf.js
this works:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
      'api-client': process.env.VUE_APP_API_CLIENT === 'mock'
            ? resolve('src/api/mock')
            : resolve('src/api/server')
    }
  },
```

and this doesn't:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
      'api-client': resolve('src/api/' + process.env.VUE_APP_API_CLIENT)
    }
  },
```

The error when running `npm run dev` is

```
This dependency was not found:
* api-client in ./src/store/index.js
```

Here's `config\prod.env.js`:

```
'use strict'
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  VUE_APP_API_CLIENT: '"server"'
}
```

and `config\dev.env.js`

```
'use strict'
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  VUE_APP_API_CLIENT: '"mock"'
})
```

How can I use the environment variable as in the first code sample?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it works correctly in the first example and doesn't always fall back to `resolve('src/api/server')`?

Comment: @George, you're right ... it doesn't work correctly, it falls back to 'src/api/server'. It seems like process.env.VUE_APP_API_CLIENT is not valid in that context.

Comment: dotenv package could solve your issue https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: @JuanCaicedo, thanks, but I'm mostly curious why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `config/dev.env.js` and `config/prod.env.js` are loaded in `webpack.dev.conf.js` and `webpack.prod.conf.js` respectively, after the `webpack.base.conf` has been loaded, therefore the env variables I declared there are unknown at the time I'm setting the aliases in `webpack.base.conf`. Strangely enough, process.env.NODE_ENV is not unknown at that place, so I ended up using it:

```
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
```

then the aliases are declared as such:

```
alias: {
  'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
  '@': resolve('src'),
  'api-client': resolve(`src/api/${isProduction ? 'server' : 'mock'}`)
}
```